# How do you build a matchmaking service for an iOS turn-based board game?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, ios, game-center

I want to build a board game that matches players with similar skill levels against each other.

Take for example a chess iOS app. Log in, and the game pairs you up against someone with a similar elo rating.

But there's a network infrastructure they're using. I haven't been able to find a suggestion for what kind of network architecture I should use.

I've tried Google and searching on YouTube for how to build a multiplayer solution, and I haven't been able to find anything specific.

The closest thing I have is to just use the built-in GameKit features Apple offers.

Otherwise I have to use some things called REST, SOAP, Amazon AWS, or Unity's UNET multiplayer matchmaking service. And that's all fine, but I haven't been able to find any specific directions on how to use those services.

What I'm trying to say: There doesn't seem to be a stock, default solution for multiplayer matchmaking in 2018.

What should I use? What can I use? Should I just stick to the basic Game Center functionality?

Should I explore other services or take a few months to build a custom-solution?

What's the most efficient route towards building a multiplayer server for a simple board game between two players?

Comment: Since you are writing a "simple board game" you probably want to stick to the default stuff. And - I dont know how good / customizeable Game Center stuff is - maye tweak that a little bit, but writing custom stuff seems like an unwarranted amount of effort for your project